# CSS rotated text with background shows some background-issues

Tags: html, css, rotation, css-transforms

I am using CSS to slightly rotate Text. The text is black on a white background, but because of the rotation part of the background has some little transparent lines going through it.
This image will show it more clearly:
[image: My issue]

```css
body {
  background: red;
}

.featured-grid-b .item-heading {
  /*Black text on white background*/
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px #fff;
  padding: 0;
  background: #fff;
  line-height: 2 !important;
  display: inline;
  color: #000;
  text-shadow: none;
}

.caption h3 {
  /*Rotate Text*/
  transform: rotate(-3deg);
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="featured-grid featured-grid-b" data-animation="fade" data-animation-speed="600" data-slide-delay="5000">
  <div class="caption caption-large">
    <h3><a href="http://www.fair-fashion-magazin.de/2019/07/03/das-nachhaltige-mode-label-people-tree/" class="item-heading">Fashion zum Verlieben: Das Fair Fashion Label People Tree</a></h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

As this is a Wordpress site, I can't really adjust the HTML and tried to achieve the result with only CSS-changes. Therefore if possible I am looking for a CSS-solution that will fix the problem.
The text should look exactly like this, with the spaces between each line of text.

Comment: try moving the `background: #fff;` to the `h3`

Comment: @ZohirSalak while this would fix the issue, I am trying to keep the shapes separated when there is more than one line of text. Adding the background to the h3 gives me one solid white shape.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a small inset box-shadow to avoid this issue *(seems to do the job only on Chrome)*

```css
.item-heading { 
    /*Black text on white background*/
    box-shadow:
      0 0 0 5px #fff,
      0 0 0 2px #fff inset;
    padding: 0;
    background: #fff;
    line-height: 2 !important;
    display: inline;
    color: #000;
    text-shadow: none;
}

.caption h3 {
    /*Rotate Text*/
    transform: rotate(-3deg);
    margin-bottom:15px;
}

body {
 background:pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="caption caption-large">                                     
<h3><a href="http://www.fair-fashion-magazin.de/2019/07/03/das-nachhaltige-mode-label-people-tree/" class="item-heading">Fashion zum Verlieben:<br> Das Fair Fashion Label People Tree</a></h3>
</div
```

Another idea is to consider border and rely on `box-decoration-break` (pay attention to the support: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-boxdecorationbreak)

```css
.item-heading { 
    /*Black text on white background*/
    border:5px solid #fff;
    padding: 0;
    background: #fff;
    line-height: 2 !important;
    display: inline;
    color: #000;
    text-shadow: none; 
    -webkit-box-decoration-break: clone;
     box-decoration-break: clone; 
}

.caption h3 {
    /*Rotate Text*/
    transform: rotate(-3deg);
    margin-bottom:15px;
}

body {
 background:pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="caption caption-large">                                     
<h3><a href="http://www.fair-fashion-magazin.de/2019/07/03/das-nachhaltige-mode-label-people-tree/" class="item-heading">Fashion zum Verlieben: <br>Das Fair Fashion Label People Tree</a></h3>
</div
```

Comment: Sorry to be a pain, but I'm still seeing a very light border around the text in Firefox

Comment: @RamSegev the `-moz-` prefix hasn't been necessary for 8 years.

Comment: @freefaller add another way

Comment: @TemaniAfif the second method doesn't work when the text wraps eg. https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6Hp8.png

Comment: While the second solution does work better, the shapes are supposed to be "separated" like they are now. Maybe there just isn't a way to get it "perfectly" on all browsers?

Comment: @Turnip yes forget the wrap, updated with a different way

Comment: @RadicalM1nd added another way, I will try to find a third one more supported and works everywhere